# Is there any guaranteed dependency of C++ system headers?

Tags: c++

For example, in `<algorithm>`, the function `equal_range` returns a `pair`, so can I assume that if I `#include <algorithm>`, `<utility>` is `#include`d?

Comment: You cannot and should not assume anything. Always include the headers for the types you actually use.

Comment: http://kera.name/articles/2010/08/tomalaks-tuesday-tip-6-an-inclusion-pitfall/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always include what you need, you cannot rely on all implementations including the same set of headers in another header.

In your example, if a function returns a pair you can be reasonably sure that the `pair` class is declared, but nothing requires the implementation to include the rest of `<utility>`.

In fact, it is impossible to implement the standard library using exactly the headers shown in the standard, because there are some circular references. Implementations must split them in smaller parts, and include those sub-headers in the required `<>` headers.

The GCC team, for example, is working to minimize the amount of inclusions to speed up compile time.

Comment: Nice explanation: it contradicts my answer, so I'm removing it.

Comment: "*if a function returns a pair you can be reasonably sure that the pair class is declared*" Indeed, declared, not defined -- if a given algorithm only uses `pair` as a dependent type, then a forward declaration will suffice, and consequently one may still have to include `utility` to get `pair`'s actual _definition_ before instantiating the algorithm's function template.

Answer (score 5):

There is never a guaranteed inclusion of header files that other headers depend on. Fortunately, it's common practice (though not certain 100% of the time) that headers are guarded against multiple inclusion -- meaning you can #include them as many times as you wish without causing harm.

Comment: If you use a (standard) library that doesn't have include guards, switch to a different library. RUN!

Comment: To add to this answer, there is also no guarantee that headers don't include other (standard) headers they don't need, so, if a standard library header wanted, it could just include the whole standard libray.

Comment: "If you use a (standard) library that doesn't have include guards, switch to a different library." If standard library does not allow multiple inclusion of its headers then it does not comply to the standard and thus not really Standard Library at all. Standard guarantees that you can include standard headers as many times as you like.

Answer (score 2):

OK, late answer, but I'll add this anyway.

It's about the `<iostream>` header. In C++98 and C++03 the standard did not guarantee that it would include `<istream>` and `<ostream>`, which meant that you were not guaranteed to have available e.g. `std::endl`. And at least one compiler insisted on being formal about it (in spite of all the non-normative examples in the standard showing the *intention*)!

Well, I can't remember who pointed it out first, but it was discussed up, down and sideways in [comp.lang.c++]. Several times. And finally James Kanze, bless his soul (well he's not dead yet, in fact he's here on SO), put it to the committee, and it was fixed for C++0x.

So, there's now one header dependency that you can depend on.

Hallelujah!

But in the other direction, C++0x increases the confusion about which headers can put which names in the global namespace and the `std` namespace. Now any standard library header corresponding to a C library header can freely pollute the global namespace, and be conforming. And so now there's no point in including, say, `<cstdio>`, but instead now the wise thing to do is to include `<stdio.h>` and accept a *guaranteed* global namespace pollution.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you should not assume anything about inclusion of headers. I have been playing around with inclusion of headers for a while, and you know i observed that when it comes to header files like vector and string, you are 'almost' sure that you are including them from somewhere.
Yes but this things are good only when you are just playing around. I would suggest you to always include the headers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee, but since `<algorithm>` uses pair internally it is common sense that it should include it. There are ways to make sure that a header file is included only once:

`#pragma once` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once

```
#ifndef MY_H
#define MY_H
 //header code
#endif /* MY_H */
```

And usually a good library will include all the needed files to compile, and those will be using this kind of mechanism to make sure that they are included only once.

There are sometimes exceptions to this rule especially in private (personal, not standard) libraries where the included header files are placed in the order needed for them to compile. And in that case if you have three includes, probably the second include uses the code from the first and the third from the first and second.

Best approach is to include all that you need to have direct access to the data structures you use.

Comment: blah, blah, c++ purist, blah, blah, pragma once, blah, blah compiler extension.

Comment: @Gleno : `#pragma once` is supported by MSVC, GCC, clang, etc.; I'm not sure this is one to get up in arms about, even for a purist. ;-]