# C++ Call Function When Variable is Requested

Tags: c++, c, class

I've see this done before in languages based on mono, but I'm just curious if this would be possible in c++. If I had the following class

```
  class test {
    public:
    int foo;
    int myfunction();
  };
```

when I try and access the foo variable, is their any way I can make it so it calls myfunction and returns its value?

```
test t;
cout << t.foo;//instead of printing the value of foo, print the return value of myfunction
```

Thanks in advance!
I googled this but wasn't able to find anything.

Or, could it be possible to call a function with no arguments without the parenthesis?

Wow! Thanks for all the input guys. The main reason I wanted no parenthesis is that I'm trying to make this API as similar to that of an old, non-c++ API. Not having two parenthesis after a function in this class might make maintenance a bit harder, but it will saves me hours of answering why Vector2.normalized has to have () after it.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: It would make working with the Vector class I'm making a bit easier.

Comment: How would it make it "easier"? Besides not having to type `()`?

Comment: @Precursor - Even if you could do it, I think it would be bad from a maintenance perspective. Think about the next guy that comes along that has to maintain your code. How intuitive do you think something like what you're proposing would be?

Comment: "Never do this" solution: `#define varName funName()`

Comment: So you dont want the variable foo at all. It does not seem to play any role in your interface as accesses to it calls a method. Thus just remove it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One possible workaround, which is a bit evil, would be to use a macro.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FOO myfunction()

class test {
  private:
    int foo;
  public:    
    int myfunction() {
      return 42;
    }
};

int main() {
  test t;
  printf("%d\n",t.FOO);
  return 0;
}
```

As I alluded to in the comments to your OP though, I think such tricks are terrible from a maintenance perspective, and should be avoided.

Comment: I sthink he used stdio for printf

Comment: @Precursor: that was his point. With C++, one should stick to `<cstdio>` or yet better, `<iostream>`.

Comment: @jweyrich - I don't think it's always best to use streams Streams are almost always slower than using printf and other native C functions. So when performance is important, one could definitely make the argument that it's better to use native C functions. However, in this example I agree it would have been fine to use cout, I just prefer printf.

Comment: @DownVoter - care to explain?

Comment: @dcp: iostream vs. cstdio is argumentative, but as you said, it makes absolute no difference to this Q&A. I just wanted to point out in C++ `cstdio` is the proper header for `printf`, not `stdio.h`.

Comment: @Alf P Steinbach - I didn't say it in jest, I said it with a stern warning to avoid the behavior. Maybe you should re-read the last part of my answer. "I think such tricks are terrible from a maintenance perspective, and should be avoided."

Comment: @jweyrich: no, with C++0x the most practical choice is `stdio.h`. `cstdio` does not in practice guarantee non-contamination of the global namespace today, and in C++0x it doesn't even guarantee that in formal-land. as it happened I wrote [a little about it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519483/is-there-any-guaranteed-dependency-of-c-system-headers/6522504#6522504) today.

Comment: @Alf: interesting, and IMO terrible - supporting what you said in that answer, "increases the confusion". Thanks for the lesson though. I'm still not well versed with C++0x.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, make `foo` private and only accessible with a public accessor method that can do whatever you want. You can't do it directly the way you asked in C++.

EDIT: If you want the behavior options you're describing, C++ may not be the language for this project.

Also I should note that the standard library already has a nicely optimized and debugged `vector` that should be used in favor of rolling your own (unless it's just an exercise).

EDIT2: Also if you're trying to do this to save on typing, remember that to save two seconds of typing now you cost yourself or the future maintainer four hours of head-scratching debugging trying to figure out why it doesn't work the way it appears that it should. You write code once and read it many times.

Comment: I described the C++ way to mostly do what was asked.

Comment: I'm not challenging that, but the OP is more concerned about not typing the parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

In general it's not a good idea to do what you request, known as **properties** in other languages.

However, I've used it to debug spaghetti code.

So, it's a tool that belongs in the toolbox, but it's not a tool you should use frequently.

Off the cuff (code not contaminated by dirty compiler's fingers):

```
class Test
{
private:
    class IntProperty
    {
    private:
        int value_;

    public:
        IntProperty( int v = 0 ): value_( v ) {}

        void setValue( int v ) { value_ = v; }
        int value() const { return value_; }

        IntProperty& operator=( int x )
        {
            setValue( x );  return *this;
        }

        operator int () const { return value(); }
    };

public:
    IntProperty foo;
};
```

One reason that this is generally ungood is that if you pass `foo` to some templated code, such as standard stream output, the conversion to `int` will not be invoked. Such places require explicit conversion calls.

Another reason that it's generally ungood is that if the setter or getter needs access to the rest of the object, then this involves a stored "outer object" pointer, which equates to some inefficiency, both memory and time.

So, instead of this monstrosity, consider simply making that datum `private`, and provide a getter function.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that in C++. If you're planning to access x,y,z members on your Vector class, you could write an `operator[]` which receives the index by argument, invokes the desired method/function, and returns the computed value for the requested member (according to the index passed). Example:

```
int& operator[](unsigned i) {
    // Be sure to write proper bounds checking here.
    doSomething(data[i]);
    return data[i];
}
```

Comment: well it can be done. but i've only used it to debug existing spaghetti code. other than such special applications it's imho generally not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can make foo a macro:

```
#define foo myfunction()
class test{
public: 
  int myfunction();
};
```

But it is a sad method.

Comment: Won't work if he has private variable named foo already in the class.

Comment: Yes, that's why I removed it.